# How prove this $\frac{a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}+\cdots+a_{p^2-q^2}}{p^2-q^2}=p^2-q^2+1$

Tags: number-theory

**Nice Question:**

> let $p,q\in N^{+}$,and $p>\sqrt{2}q\ge \sqrt{2}$

show that:
there are exsit $a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},\cdots,a_{p^2-q^2}$ such
$a_{i},(i=1,2,\cdots,p^2-q^2)$ are all positive square numbers,and such

> $$\dfrac{a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}+\cdots+a_{p^2-q^2}}{p^2-q^2}=p^2-q^2+1$$

**My try:since**

$a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{p^2-q^2}$ are all square numbers,so let

$a_{i}=m^2_{i},m\in N$

> and
>   $$a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{p^2-q^2}=(p^2-q^2+1)(p^2-q^2)$$
>   so
>   $$m^2_{1}+m^2_{2}+\cdots+m^2_{p^2-q^2}=(p^2-q^2)^2+(p^2-q^2)$$
>   exsit solution.
>   so we only prove following equation have
>   $$m^2_{1}+m^2_{2}+\cdots+m^2_{p^2-q^2}+q^2=(p^2-q^2)^2+p^2$$
>   exsit solution?

But I can't it? Thank you

Comment: If the squares are allowed to be zero, then you can use the four square theorem to prove this when $p^2-q^2\geq 4$. This leaves the question of $q=1$ and $p=2$.

Comment: Sorry,I have edit,$a_{i}$ is positive square numbers

Comment: Note that $(p^2-q^2)(p^2-q^2)+1$ is an oblong (a.k.a. pronic) number, which is (by definition) twice a triangular number. There are lots of identities linking triangular and square numbers — perhaps that's where to look?